# Convert to Postgres function

Tags: postgresql

I am converting my SQL stored procedure to Postgres function but it is resulting error in one of the statement as

ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 7:           CAST(time(0), '00:00' + (h.hour  * interval '1Hour...
                              ^

Below is my Postgres function and SQL Store procedure which i am converting.Please tell me where i am getting wrong.

```css
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shiftwisedata_sp(INOut shift_id bigint,InOut userdate date,OUT shift_name character varying (50),OUT from_time character varying(50),OUT to_time character varying(50),OUT cal bigint)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
  BEGIN
return query
SELECT userdate, s.shift_name, 
          CAST(time(0), '00:00' + (h.hour  * interval '1Hour')) AS from_time,
           CAST(time(0), '00:00' + ((h.hour + 1)  * interval '1Hour')) AS to_time,
          COALESCE(r.Readings, 0) AS readings
   FROM   shift_wise s
   CROSS  JOIN (VALUES(0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9),
                      (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19),
                      (20), (21), (22), (23)) AS h(hour)
   OUTER  APPLY (SELECT SUM(r.param_value) AS Readings
                 FROM   table_1 r
                 WHERE  r.timestamp_col >= CAST(userdate as timestamp without time zone) + (h.hour  * interval '1Hour')
                   AND  r.timestamp_col < CAST(userdate as timestamp without time zone) + ((h.hour + 1) * interval '1Hour')) AS r
WHERE s.shift_id = shift_id
 AND (s.to_time > s.from_time              AND 
       h.hour >= date_part(HOUR, s.from_time) AND
       h.hour <  date_part(HOUR, s.to_time) 
    OR
      s.to_time < s.from_time AND
         (h.hour >= date_part(HOUR, s.from_time) OR
          h.hour < date_part(HOUR, s.to_time))
       )
      ORDER BY s.to_time;
 
  END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

```css
CREATE PROCEDURE Shiftdata @date date, @shiftid int AS
   SELECT @date, s.Shift_Name, 
           convert(time(0), dateadd(HOUR, h.hour, '00:00')) AS from_time,
           convert(time(0), dateadd(HOUR, h.hour + 1, '00:00')) AS to_time,
          coalesce(r.Readings, 0) AS readings
   FROM   Shift_Wise s
   CROSS  JOIN (VALUES(0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9),
                      (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19),
                      (20), (21), (22), (23)) AS h(hour)
   OUTER  APPLY (SELECT SUM(r.Reading_Col) AS Readings
                 FROM   Reading r
                 WHERE  r.Timestamp_Col >= dateadd(HOUR, h.hour, convert(datetime, @date))
                   AND  r.Timestamp_Col < dateadd(HOUR, h.hour + 1, convert(datetime, @date))) AS r
WHERE s.Shift_ID = @shiftid
  AND (s.to_time > s.from_time              AND 
       h.hour >= datepart(HOUR, s.from_time) AND
       h.hour <  datepart(HOUR, s.to_time) 
    OR
      s.to_time < s.from_time AND
         (h.hour >= datepart(HOUR, s.from_time) OR
          h.hour < datepart(HOUR, s.to_time))
       )
ORDER BY s.to_time
```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't how the CAST works in Postgresql. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createcast.html

```
('00:00' + (h.hour  * interval '1Hour'))::time
```

is easiest to read (IMHO) if you don't mind using the non-standard :: notation.

Comment: CAST('00:00' + (h.hour  * interval '1Hour') as timestamp without time zone) AS from_time this is how i have modified is this right ?

Comment: That looks good as the portable solution. (I'll let you decide if you want a time, timestamp, etc.)

Comment: Now,instaed of outer apply i am using left join latreal is postgres but it is resulting error in where s.shift_id = shiftid below is what i am writing   LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT SUM(r.param_value) AS Readings
                 FROM   table_1 r
                 WHERE  r.timestamp_col >= CAST(userdate as timestamp without time zone ) + h.hour  * interval '1Hour'
                   AND  r.timestamp_col < CAST(userdate as timestamp without time zone ) + (h.hour + 1) * interval '1Hour') AS r 
                   Where s.shift_id = shiftid

Comment: I have to admit, I have never used a LATERAL join, just LEFT [OUTER]. (OUTER is optional)

Answer (score 0):

Finally,
Converted SQL SP into Postgres Function and got the desired result

```css
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION shiftwisedata_sp(IN shiftid bigint, INOUT userdate date, OUT shift_name character varying, OUT from_time time without time zone, OUT to_time time without time zone, OUT readings bigint)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
  BEGIN
  return query
SELECT userdate, s.shift_name, 
          ('00:00' + (h.hour  * interval '1Hour'):: time) AS from_time,
          ('00:00' + ((h.hour + 1)  * interval '1Hour'):: time) AS to_time,
          COALESCE(r.Readings, 0) AS readings
   FROM   shift_wise s
  CROSS  JOIN (VALUES(0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9),
                      (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19),
                      (20), (21), (22), (23)) AS h(hour)
   LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT CAST(SUM(r.param_value) as bigint) AS Readings
                 FROM   table_1 r
                 WHERE  r.timestamp_col >= (CASt(userdate As timestamp without time zone)  + h.hour  * interval '1Hour')
                   AND  r.timestamp_col < (CASt(userdate As timestamp without time zone) + (h.hour + 1) * interval '1Hour')
                   ) AS r ON TRUE
WHERE s.shift_id = shiftid
 AND (s.to_time > s.from_time              AND 
       h.hour >= Extract(HOUR from CAST(s.from_time as time)) AND
       h.hour <  Extract(HOUR from CAST(s.to_time as time)) 
    OR
      s.to_time < s.from_time AND
         (h.hour >= Extract(HOUR from CAST(s.from_time as time)) OR
          h.hour < Extract(HOUR from CAST(s.to_time as time))
       ))
      ORDER BY s.to_time; 
  END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```